# Is there a equivalent to mac's active corners on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, macos

I like the **active/hot corner** feature on mac's. This feature triggers an action in case user places mouse pointer into a corner. So 4 different actions can be defined. Note that when you repeat the mouse movement to the same corner the everything will be as it was before.

I like the most

- `show desktop`
- `show all open applications` from which I can make one of them active.

Is there any equivalent to this on **Windows** (Windows 7)? I particularly want to access desktop and see all open applications.

Comment: Please explain in detail what this feature is and what you want it to do in your case. Windows user might not know what the OS X feature does, but would be perfectly capable of answering when given a description.

Comment: Not an answer, but I expect many Windows users use Windows+M keys instead. Or right-click the task-bar.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick: hm, why do I have to use keyboard when I do not have to? Win+M gives me desktop but next press of Win+M don't restore everything at it was before. Good point though.

Comment: @Radek you can press `Shift+Win+M` to restore all as it was before after minimizing with `Win+M` :).

Comment: And if you want to open a particular one then you can use `Win+1-9` key combination which will open the exact one as you want. But you have to remember the sequence in this pattern.

Comment: @avirk: didn't know about the shifty thing :-) and it's standard windows behaviour :-) still why to use keyboard if I don't have to...

Comment: @Radek take a look on [HotCorners](https://sites.google.com/site/programsforpeers/hotcorners). I have not used it personal so can't say too much about it, but it seems to promise what you want.

Comment: There is nothing Inbuilt but some third party s/w can provide similar feature.

Comment: Some versions of win7 also provide a very nice look at all running applications by using `Win+tab`.

Comment: Windows 8 uses hot corners, but I don't think they're configurable.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't look like there's a direct equivalent.

You can see all open applications along the task bar (usually located at the bottom of the screen).

You can hide all currently open application (to show the desktop) by clicking on the "Show Desktop" button which is normally at the right hand end of the task bar. If you hover the mouse over this area (without clicking) the open applications will become totally transparent - all you will see is their borders. When you move the mouse away the applications are restored.

[image: The Windows Taskbar]

The Windows+M key also hides all open applications.

Comment: Yes, I know that but .. the mac's version is bit more easy to use. Your example of open applications shows only IE windows. I have to be quite exact to click the "Show Destop" button compare to active corners where you 'only' move the mouse somewhere where the corner is and you get what you want. Win+M gives me desktop but next press of Win+M don't restore everything at it was before.

Comment: @Radek - hover over the button

Comment: This applies only to one application. So I can see all IE or firefox windows. I am using it but something is missing, don't you think?

Comment: @Radek - there probably isn't a direct equivalent.

Comment: :-( it seems to me too as for my google search. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try win+d. It will give you desktop and pressing again restores previous state.

Comment: @Lamb - just tried Win+D and it didn't work.

Comment: @ChrisF Its strange, it works for me. Actually its just an Alternative to clicking on the taskbar end to show desktop and vice-versa.

Answer (score 4):

There is not any inbuilt feature in Windows for the active corners, but you can use a third party tool for that like [Hot Corners](https://sites.google.com/site/programsforpeers/hotcorners).  When you launch its setup, right click on it and then choose the option `Run as Administrator` and it will install successfully; otherwise, you will get an error during installation.

**If you want to use the keyboard shortcuts in that case**

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to open a panel that lets you pick  the application that should be focused. And <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>1-9</kbd> key will open the particular app in the taskbar sequence.

Comment: Can't wait to try the tool on my home computer...